# Select one row that is a duplicate and also select the other rows that are not duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

here is my code

```
select i.RefNo,i.Premium,i.Description from (select d.Description,c.IsActiveRecord,c.RefNo,c.MovementID, c.Premium,ROW_NUMBER() 
over(partition by c.premium order by c.refno) n from lif_mgm_t_contract c 
inner join SDT_LJG_T_MovementDescription d with (nolock) on c.MovementID = d.MovementID ) i
   where i.n = 1 and i.MovementID <> 0
```

so for instance

table

```
a
a
b
```

I want the query to return

```
a
b and not just a hope this makes sense --only a beginner
```

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with your sample data.

Comment: initially i had duplicates so i wrote that code and now it only returns only one 1

Comment: How would you do it? @GordonLinoff

Comment: your code was trying to eliminate the duplicate rows for each `premium` group, what is wrong with that?

Comment: @Percy can you share your sample db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using a group by clause

```
SELECT OrderNumber
  FROM AccountOrder
  group by OrderNumber
```

so if my table has the following order numbers

```
1
2
2
3
```

the query would return

```
1
2
3
```